# Can neural network help me with detecting center coordinates of particles in an image?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image of some nano particles that was taken with Scanning Electron Microscope (SEM) attached here. I want to obtain center points coordinates (x,y) for each particle. Doing it by hand is very tedious. Since I just started to learn Machine Learning and got introduced to Artificial Neural Networks and kinda understand that they they are helpful with image classification, I am curious if I can use these tools to achieve my goal.

I found this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.04010.pdf) where they discuss kind similar work,,, but I am curious if you have seen anything practical or if you can give me some steps where and how to start, that's really helpful.
Any guidance is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard problem, you have many overlapping points with objects which aren't completely round. I'm not very knowledgeable on CV but I suspect you will find it very challenging.

I would probably say a handcrafted detection algorithm would probably be easier, something like an edge detector which fit circles to arcs and labeled the points. But it's still going to be nontrivial and maybe impossible to get it working with high accuracy.